# How to Display year only Calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I am using Predefined bootstrap calendar in my page. Its working Properly, but for few text box I need to display year only calendar.

**My Codes are**

```
<!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/adminlte/components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">


 <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <script src="~/Content/adminlte/components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

 <script>
        $(function () {

            $('#Date').datepicker({
                autoclose: true
            })
        })</script>
```

**Design**

```
  <label>Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
 <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="Date">
 <div class="input-group-addon">
 <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**My datpicker with text box image as follows**

[image]

Its working fine to pickup a date. 
**But for few text box I need year only option as shown in image below**

[image]

If I use code from some other stackoverflow answers or from [this link code](https://forums.asp.net/t/2011715.aspx?only%20year%20show%20in%20jquery%20datepicker) , it affect my date picker design and it also change the option for all text boxes to choose normal date also...  Kindly help.. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this config [options](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewmode):

```
$("#Date").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Answer Work like awesome. I can make ur answer as right answer only after 10 mins. SO I will tick the answer after 10 mins. THank U once again.

Comment: @Riya, thanks.. yes you can change as Date/Month/Year   ```$("#Date").datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  }) ```

Comment: yes sir I tried that one already and worked for me so I edited my comment and remove that 2nd question.. but thank u once again for ur reply

Answer (score -1):

Look if you go to jquery page and searched for calender.
They will tell you the properties for calender format and how to use them and thus you copy and paste thrm in your bootstrap calender since it will be the same.
Regards.